# Adding thematic break after iterating through an object

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, each

I'm using $.each to iterate through an object and I'm struggling to add a thematic break after every 7th property:value.

```
$.each(element, function (key, value) {
  $("#result1").append(key + ": " + value + "<br>");
});
```

I'm using the above code and I'm able to display each property:value on a new line on the browser, but just can't figure out how to add the thematic break.  Is it even possible?

Any suggestions would be most welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to track the index, or implement a counter as I have here, and use the modulus (remainder) operator [`%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) to insert a break on the interval you want.

> The remainder operator (%) returns the remainder left over when one operand is divided by a second operand.

```js
const element = {1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three', 4: 'four', 5: 'five', 6: 'six', 7: 'seven', 8: 'eight'};

let i = 0;
$.each(element, function (key, value) {
  if (i%7 === 0) $("#result1").append("<hr />");
  
  $("#result1").append(key + ": " + value +"<br>");
  
  i++;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="result1"></div>
```

Or using plain js...

```js
const element = {1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three', 4: 'four', 5: 'five', 6: 'six', 7: 'seven', 8: 'eight'};

let result = document.getElementById('result1');

Object.entries(element).forEach(([key, value], i) => {
  if (i%7 === 0) result.innerHTML += '<hr />';
 
  result.innerHTML += `${key}: ${value} <br>`;
});
```

```html
<div id="result1"></div>
```

Comment: That is absolutely amazing! Thank you for your help.

Comment: Happy to help! Perhaps you could [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer?